# Polymer: paper-autocomplete set value

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have a paper-autocomplete element as follows inside a `<paper-card>`

```
<paper-autocomplete label="Select HWName" 
                    id="HWName" 
                    on-autocomplete-selected="onDeviceSelect" 
                    no-label-float="true"></paper-autocomplete>
```

in a given html file. I am accessing this from another file as follows

```
var hwName = document.querySelector("#HWName");
```

I need to be able to set some value in its input area on refresh, which i've remembered using localStorage API. I tried using

```
 hwName.value = "test" 
         or 
 hwName.label = "test"
```

but it doesn't work. Even tried using `setOption(option)` as described [here](http://ellipticaljs.github.io/paper-autocomplete/components/paper-autocomplete/) but doesn't work.

Is it possible to show some value on the `paper-autocomplete` element? I don't want to type, it should just set the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `text` property of `paper-autocomplete`.

So your code will be like

```
 hwName.text = "test"
```